# (When) Is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(a+bk)^Nx^k$ positive for all $0 < x < 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series

I have been stuck with this problem for while. So hope someone will give me a hint how to solve it.

> For $a$ and $b$ are positive real number, is it true that 
>   $$
> S = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}{{\left( {a + bk} \right)}^N}{x^k}}  \ge 0 
> $$
>   with all $x \in (0,\,1)$ and all positive integers $N$? If not, find the condition on $a$ and $b$ that makes the inequality true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by setting :
$$f_n(x):= \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n\,(-x)^k$$
this implies that :
$$f_0(x)=\frac 1{1+x}\quad\text{and for}\ n\ge 0\ \text{:}$$
$$x\,f_n(x)'=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{n+1}\,(-x)^{k-1}x=f_{n+1}(x)$$ 
and more generally :
$$f_{n+1}(x)=\left(x\frac d{dx}\right)^n\left(\frac 1{1+x}\right)$$
For $N=1$ your series becomes (since $f_1(x)=-x/(1+x)^2$) :
$$S_1(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (a + bk)(-x)^k=af_0(x)+bf_1(x)=\frac {a(1+x)-bx}{(1+x)^2}$$
Clearly $\,S_1(x)\ge 0\;$ requires $x$ to verify $\;a \le (b-a)x$

We could expand $(a+bk)^N$ to get results for values of $N>1$ but prefer to observe that :
$$x\,S_N(x)' = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k(a + bk)(-x)^k$$
so that (starting with the expression for $S_1(x)$) we get directly :
$$S_{N+1}(x)=a\,S_N(x)+b\,x\,S_N(x)'$$

Wishing you inspiration to finish this,